# Function in a select option not triggering when using Chrome

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following select structure. The problem is that it works only in Firefox (last version). If I use Chrome (last version) for example, the onSelection() function won't trigger. The point of it is to select a node and save it in selectedNode for further use. I found people having similar issues but none of the solutions worked for me. Thanks in advance.

**component.html**

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="selectedNode" required>
  <option *ngFor="let node of tenant.nodes" (click)="onSelection()" [ngValue]="node">{{node}}</option>
</select>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class TESTComponent {
 selectedNode: string
 tenant: Tenant = {name:'asd',nodes:['node1','node2']};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , `(click)="onSelection()"` should not be on `option` tag , and Second you need changed value so use `(change)` instead of `(click)`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedNode" (change)="onSelection()" required>
  <option *ngFor="let node of tenant.nodes" [ngValue]="node">{{node}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Battalgazi, My Pleasure , :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [ngModel]="selectedNode" required>
  <option *ngFor="let node of tenant.nodes" [ngValue]="node">{{node}}</option>
</select>
```

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inside-ngmodel